# Problem with the instalation of SenseNet in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sensenet

I am installing Sense / Net at the same time that I follow the guide of this link: http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_web_deployment_package_(IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0)

The problem arises when I have to import the application Zip into the IIS. After this point it is no longer possible to follow the tutorial, the Zip content does not match that of the tutorial and the following windows do not skip to configure the database, I am trying to download another version of sensenet from the official website, but it is not possible , just let me download the version I have already (Occupies 3GB).

Server Features:
Windows Server 2008 R2,
SQL Server 2014 Express,
IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in the article that you've mentioned there's a more recent version of this install article in the community site here: http://community.sensenet.com/docs/install-sn-from-nuget
Please use the docs on the [community site](http://community.sensenet.com) for up-to-date info.